# build.imp.xml errors and run.xml

Tags: xml

im extremly new to java and netbeans , just started studying cpsc202 , and they told us to work on netbeans , when i download it with jdk , all went fine , until when i try to run anyprogram it gives me these errors

[image: image 1]

i've read that u need to build and clean , but also when i do that , it gives me another errors

[image]

can you help me ?

Comment: This will help you get started with Java in NetBeans: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html#

Comment: as u can see on the picture , im trying to print "Hi"

Comment: any helpers please ?